# One-To-Many Relationship Query

Tags: mysql

I am really stuck on how to create the appropriate select statement and would appreciate any guidance you can offer.

I have created a mini document management system that allows users to upload files and to categorize those files by categories.  Each file can have one or many categories selected.  Following are my tables:

**Table: files (pKey (primary key), file_name, file_description, file_path)**

```
pKey  file_name  file_description        file_path
1     IT001.DOC  Network Design Document /common/it/
2     IT002.DOC  Desktop Standards       /common/it/
3     IT003.DOC  Laptop Standards        /common/it/
```

*There are other departments in addition from IT so the path field also changes (Just thought I would toss that bit of datum in)*

**Table: categories (pKey (primary key), category_description)**

```
pKey  category_description
1     Central Missouri Campus
2     Eastern Missouri Campus
3     Western Missouri Campus
4     Desktops
5     Laptops
6     Networks
7     Printers
```

*Of course there are other categories as well, this is just a sampling*

**Table: category_xref (pKey (primary key), fk_file_id, fk_category_id)**

```
pKey  fk_file_id  fk_category_id
1     1           1
2     1           2
3     1           6
4     2           2
5     2           3
6     2           4
7     3           1
8     3           2
9     3           3
10    3           5
```

When the user searches for related documents they are presented a form with the Category checkboxes.  By choosing Central, they get all files that have been marked as Central.  By choosing Desktops, they get any documents that have been marked as Desktops.  However, when they select Central AND Desktops they get any document that is either Central OR Desktops.  I need to figure out how to get only those documents that are BOTH Central AND Desktops AND any other checkboxes they have selected, and exclude any that do not contain ALL the checkboxes selected.

```
SELECT f.pkID, f.file_name, f.file_description, f.file_path, cox.fk_category_id 
FROM files f
JOIN category_xref  cox ON cox.fk_file_id = f.pkID
WHERE cox.fk_category_id IN (59, 69)
ORDER BY f.file_name ASC, cox.fk_category_id ASC
```

Comment: this is not one to many... this is many to many :). "A file has N categories and, inside a category there are N files" NxN

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would probably be:

```
SELECT f.pkID, f.file_name, f.file_description, f.file_path
FROM files f
JOIN category_xref  cox ON cox.fk_file_id = f.pkID
WHERE cox.fk_category_id IN (59, 69)
GROUP BY f.pkID
HAVING count(distinct cox.fk_category_id)=2
ORDER BY f.file_name ASC
```

Comment: @pleasedontbelong: Only that you will only get one row per file, instead of one row per file per category, as in the original query. Of course, if you only *want* one row per file, this would actually be an improvement.

Comment: Quick question on Mark's solution.  The HAVING COUNT .. = 2.  Do I assume correctly that the 2 is the number of selected checkboxes, in this case checkboxes 59 and 69?

Comment: @JohnJost: Yes - so if you had 3 checkboxes checked, the HAVING COUNT would have to be 3, and so on.

Comment: Can I expand this SELECT to add in my tag table? Each of the documents can not only have categories, but document tags as well.  So each of the files may also link to a Tag_Xref table similar to the category_tag  table above. SELECT f.pkID, f.file_name, f.file_description, f.file_path
FROM files f
JOIN category_xref  cox ON cox.fk_file_id = f.pID
JOIN tag_xref t ON t.fk_fk_file_id = f.pID)
WHERE cox.fk_category_id IN (59, 69)
AND t.fk_tag_id IN (50, 60)
GROUP BY f.pkID
HAVING count(distinct cox.fk_category_id)=2
AND count(distinct t.fk_tag_id) = 2
ORDER BY f.file_name ASC

Comment: This appears to work, but I will do some extensive testing against my test cases.  Many, MANY thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something in these lines:

```
SELECT f.pkID, f.file_name, f.file_description, f.file_path
FROM files f
RIGHT JOIN category_xref  cox1 ON cox.fk_file_id = f.pkID AND cox1.fk_category_id = 59 
RIGHT JOIN category_xref  cox2 ON cox.fk_file_id = f.pkID AND cox2.fk_category_id = 69 
ORDER BY f.file_name ASC
```

Comment: will work only on a few cases... if the file has 10 categories you'd need to do 10 joins

Comment: Is there a problem I'm not aware of in doing 10 joins?

Comment: the problem is performance... This solution will work but it might be really slow

Comment: I will need to run a benchmark to be sure, but I don't see a reason why it will be slower. Would love to get reference to a relevant benchmark or explanation.